# Should repr method in python always return string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new in Python. I have written the below code --

```
class AF:   
    def __repr__(self):
        return  {'name':1, 'age':44}

c = AF()        
print(c.__repr__())
print(repr(c))
```

When I run this, it is generating below error --

```
{'name': 1, 'age': 44}
print(repr(c))
TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type dict)
```

I read in Python documentation that **repr** should return string, OK got it, then why the first print statement ran successfully and printed the dictionary and the second print generated error? Shouldnot both the calls have failed? Trying to understand what is happening internally here.

Comment: ``c.__repr__()`` is just an arbitrary method call - it conventionally *should*  return a string but it does not have to. It just happens to be what is called by ``repr(c)`` and various other parts which *do* require strings.

Comment: The language cannot stop you from returning something other than a `str`, but that doesn't mean uses that *expect* a `str` to be returned will continue to work properly if you do. Such protocols cannot be enforced by Python's dynamic type system; it's up to the programmer to cooperate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that the built-in `repr` function is performing an additional check on the return type of the instance's `__repr__` function and raising an error if it is not a `str` as expected, whereas the `__repr__` function when called directly, as any other function, can return any value

Answer (score 0):

The `__repr__` isn't just an ordinary method, it's a special built-in function that looks a lot like operators. These operators offer more than any method can offer.

When you called `c.__repr__()` you are calling the method part. On the other hand, when you called `repr(c)`, you have called the operator. Same with `__add__` operator. It can be called as a normal method `a.__add__(b)` or it can be used as an operator (which would require more assertions) like so `a + b`